# How to get all tags from a HTML code?

Tags: php, html

How to get all tags from a HTML code inside a string?

Example:

```
$HTML = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="main">Hello World!</p>
        <img src="wallpaper.png">
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

getTags($HTML);
```

Print out (return Array) - Tags:

```
array(html, head, meta, title, body, p, img)
```

or

Print out - Tags with id attribute:

```
array(html, head, meta, title, body, [p, main], img)
```

Just FYI, I am new to HTML.

Comment: The heredoc has no relevance to the question. `$HTML` is a string like any other.

Comment: @Havenard So I would have to declare `$Html` only as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does everything but print out the ids, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out:

```
<?php
$html = '<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="main">Hello World!</p>
    <img src="wallpaper.png">
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$list=array();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($elements as $child)
{
  $list[]= $child->nodeName;
}
?>
```

Answer:

```
Array ( [0] => html [1] => head [2] => meta [3] => title [4] => body [5] => p [6] => img )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a HTML parser to read the string. A quick Google indicates you can do this with PHP directly: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

I'm sure there are other decent HTML parsers available, too.